# Log-log regression where variables are in terms of growth rate

Tags: elasticity, logarithm

I would like to estimate elasticity of exchange rate on export. The specification takes the following form:
$$Exp=\alpha+\beta_0REER+\beta_1GDP^{p}+\epsilon$$
where, $Exp$ is export growth calculated as $100*r$ ($r$ is growth rate), $REER$ is real effective exchange rate, $GDP^{p}$ is foreign GDP
s growth rate (similar to export growth).
In order to estimate elasticity of exchange rate on export is it correct to take log transformation of the export and GDP time series, if they are in terms of growth rate?

Comment: What is "elasticity of exchange rate on export". Is it function of $Exp, REER, GDP^{p}$. If yes, could you give us the function.

Comment: @a_statistician An elasticity is econ jargon for $\frac{d \log y}{d \log x}$, a unitless measure that tells you the percent change in $y$ given a percent in $x$. It's the derivative in log-log space. An elasticity relates to the usual derivative via. $\frac{d \log y}{d \log x} = \frac{x}{y} \cdot \frac{dy}{dx}.$

Comment: @MatthewGunn In this case, which one is x, and which one is y?EXP, REER, GDP.

Comment: @MatthewGunn Export is dependent variable.

Comment: @MatthewGunn I know that if my data were raw data, I mean in level, therefore if I take the log of the data I'll obtain the coefficient as elasticity. But if I my data (export, gdp) is expressed in terms of growth rates, then taking log of growth rates is it reasonable?

Comment: @MatthewGunn I would like to articulate my problem again, since I think that I did it in a unclear way. So, my aim is to estimate exchange rate (REER) elasticity, in other words, the impact of REER on export. But I've a constraint. My all variables are I(1) (also there isn't cointegration), therefore I take time series in growth (100*r, where r is growth rate). My question is: whether I still obtain elasticity, when I estimate log-log model with time series in terms of growth?